# C++ How to access an object initialized in main() from outside of main()?

Tags: c++

My main() looks like this:

```
   int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    ...

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    ...

    // Set robot's parameters
    Robot robot; // Initialize global object robot
    robot.setSize(50);
    robot.setColor('G');
    robot.setLocation(50,100);

    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then I have another function, which I would like to have access to the methods of the robot:

```
// This function is constantly "looped"
void display() {
    ...
    robot.draw();
    ...
}
```

What is the legit way to do it in C++?

Comment: Show where and how you call draw()?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry, I was unclear.

Comment: @user1739770, So `display` is a self-made function that needs a specific signature in order to be passed into `glutDisplayFunc`? I know how to circumvent that, but I need confirmation.

Comment: @chris, Yes, I believe so. glutDisplayFunc() can take any void function and loops it until the program is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested, the question changed, so my old answer is lost to the edits.

If your `display` function is required to have a specific signature (`void()`), you can use `std::bind`, presuming you have access to C++11:

```
void display(Robot &robot){...}

//in main
Robot robot;
glutDisplayFunc(std::bind(std::ref(display), robot));
```

If you don't have C++11, `boost::bind` works just as well:

```
glutDisplayFunc(boost::bind(boost::ref(display), robot));
```

If you have neither, you'll have to store `robot` more globally.

Comment: My bad I didn't read the question fully before answering. +1.

Comment: @w00te, Can't say I haven't done that on multiple occasions. It's funny when you barely post an answer, and then see that your answer was something mentioned in the question that you happened not to see somehow.

Comment: Thank You. I tried doing it the way you said, but when I call `glutDisplayFunc(display(robot));` I get an error `main.cpp:40:35: error: invalid use of void expression` :(

Comment: @user1739770, Yes, you're calling the function, which returns `void`, and is not legal in that context. If you have access to either of the aforementioned tools, you must bind the argument to the function. I'm not sure how it works, but it somehow keeps whatever `Robot` you bind, but the function keeps the `void()` signature. Perhaps you could be inspired by boost's to make your own if you don't have boost or C++11.

Comment: Since glut is a C interface this solution won't work, by the way (I don't know why the questioner accepted it as his personal solution). Glut needs to provide the ability to specify and receive an arbitrary `void*` (as is usually the case for well-designed C interfaces) so that the client can pass a class instance pointer, for example. If it has no such interface, then there needs to be a global place for this robot to live, probably in a global `Application` class. I can't recall which glut expects.

Comment: @GManNickG, I had no idea it was C only. That's right, then. A class holding these related global items that experience this problem would really be the only option, apart from making them purely global.

Answer (score 1):

Since the glut display callback doesn't take parameters, you will have to use a global variable (Robot * gRobot; ) or a singleton pattern.